# How to access objects within objects in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

PowerShell v5.0 running on Windows 10 Pro.
Calling script as:
$Test = RunMyScript
works fine.
$Test contains this:

```
itemthefirst         : afa;lskejrpoieqqrelkj
Id                   : a;slkdjfepoieuprwieurep
anotherID            : 28fa26f71
computername..       : somecomputer
Volumes              : {Level1.Level2.Level3.Metadata.Storage.Volume,Level1.Level2.Level3.Metadata.Storage.Volume, Level1.Level2.Level3.Metadata.Storage.Volume,Level1.Level2.Level3.Metadata.Storage.Volume}
```

I am assuming that the item returned in the "Volumes" field is a list of volumes.

How do I access that data returned in the Volumes Field?
$Test.Volumes produces this:

```
$Test.Volumes
Level1.Level2.Level3.Metadata.Storage.Volume
Level1.Level2.Level3.Metadata.Storage.Volume
Level1.Level2.Level3.Metadata.Storage.Volume
Level1.Level2.Level3.Metadata.Storage.Volume
```

Thanks,

Comment: I'm going to guess `works fine.` isn't actually true, and it works not-fine, and is casting some complex objects to useless strings internally, and you can't get the data back. Maybe not though -if you `$test.Volumes[0].GetType()` what type is it? and `$test.Volumes[0] | fl *` ?

Comment: My apologies for not including that in the original question.
`PS C:\windows> $Test.Volumes[0]`
`Cannot index into a null array.` -- which is why I thought it may be an object in its own right

Comment: ... oh. But doesn't that imply it's $null, when it isn't in your earlier output? What does `$Test.Volumes | Get-Member` do?

Comment: It is amazing the difference a misplaced period can make.
With your help we've discovered that the Volumes member contains an array of dotted strings.  Thanks -- I think we can drop this topic now.